# JSONP Help (No jQuery)

Tags: ajax, json, jsonp, javascript

I'm trying hard here to figure out how to do a JSONP request, but everywhere I look for reference material is all jQuery examples. I can read the jQuery source, but I wanted a clean and simple example. I'm building a library for something and I dont want to include jQuery, so please, no jQuery `$.getJSON`. I know how to do use that.

My server spits out the normal `callback({"foo":"bar"})` response with a `content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8` MIME.

So if I put in a script tag like (using Twitter since I KNOW their API works):

```
<script src="http://twitter.com/users/oscargodson.json?callback=test"></script>
```

Or dynamically. Either works and I get the JSON, its the next step I can't figure out.

If I do just `console.log(test)` after the script loads I get: `Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined`

Why? How, after i get the response from the server, do I then pass that to myself? On my own server if i do `callback = {"foo":"bar"}` callback works and returns an object, but not the way above. How come? Ive only used AJAX libraries to do this, but for this project I need to code it myself :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set "callback=test", then in your client code you need to have a function called "test" that takes the json value from the server and handles it for you.

JQuery does just that, with a dynamically-generated function name.

```
function test(data) { console.log(data) }
get_jsonp("http://www.example.com/?callback=test")
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple script inclusion should do the job:

```
function test(res) {
    // TODO: manipulate the results here like for example showing
    // the created_at property
    alert(res.created_at);    
}

window.onload = function() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = 'http://twitter.com/users/oscargodson.json?callback=test';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
};
```

And here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RS3PN/2/).

Obviously you shouldn't forget that browsers might cache static resources such as scripts so if you want to ensure fresh information you could adapt some timestamp to the url.